# Changing fetch request url dynamically when state updates in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am currently working in a project which I need to consume an API to render the content. However I need to to make another request if the user changes the language. So to implement this dynamically I've inserted at the end of the URL a state called "langPage" (because only the page will change on the API) as you can see below:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let urlData = 'https://beta.estudiocru.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/'+ this.state.langPage;
    console.log(urlData);
    fetch(urlData)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        aboutContent: response,
      })
    });

    let logoURL = 'https://beta.estudiocru.com/' + this.state.lang + 'wp-json/wp/v2/acf/options';
    fetch(logoURL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        options: res
      })
    });
  }
```

The problem is that when the state changes the fetch doesn't update and this is because I am calling it on `componentDidMount`. So I would like to know how could I make another request when the state updates and re-render the new content on the page.

I am just getting started with react. I would appreciate a lot if someone could help me out.

Comment: everytime state changes, component renders, why dont you call this in render?

Comment: Thanks Hashbytes! The URL changes correctly but the content doesn't. It is still the same content of the first fetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move fetch to `componentDidUpdate()` it will work every time state or prop changed.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
   if(this.state.lang !== prevState.lang) {
       // fetch ...
   }
}
```